# How do I restrict my friends from seeing my posts that I put in private pages?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I don't want my friends to see whatever posts I put in public or private pages. I want to restrict them for a few posts. Is it possible? Only the people who ever liked that page, are supposed to see the posts / comments.

Answer (score 1):

Well, The question is quite contradictory. You say "public" pages. Hence, your friends are also "Public". There is no way to change such Privacy Options. Only Solution is to "Block" the friend to whom you don't want your post to display.